# PHPUnit: Warning: require(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 42

Tags: phpunit, osx-lion, mamp

when running

- phpunit

I get error

```
Warning: require(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 42

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 42
```

/usr/local/bin/phpunit displays the following on line 42:

```
require 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```

any suggestions how to fix this?

**Update (1):**

I was missing php.ini in /etc/, so I symlinked it to read the MAMP php.ini. Now I get

```
php -r 'foreach (explode(":", get_include_path()) as $path) echo $path . PHP_EOL;'
.
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php
/usr/local/bin/pear
/usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit
```

running

- phpunit

is running but provides no output.

Any suggestions what to check next?

**Update (2):**

probably the root cause of this issue is related to question

- [MAMP PEAR configuration is pointing to local directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482265/mamp-pear-configuration-is-pointing-to-local-directories).

Answer (score 13):

I hit a similar issue on MAC OSX Lion.  I installed phpunit with the PEAR package manager, and when I try to run it I got the error as described by udo.  I was able to resolve it with the following simple steps:

1. Get the latest php archive of pear `curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.php`
2. Install the archive with `sudo php -q go-pear.php`

During installation, it detects if the include_path in your php.ini does not contain the PEAR PHP directory. You can choose to let it fix it for you automatically when given the option.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'd like to add something, after these steps I had to install phpunit again using the following commands:
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit

Comment: same, thanks - updated command -- $ sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de; sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no; sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com; sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit

Comment: I thought PHPunit was moving away from PEAR completely. Is there a way to get VPU working with a composer-installed version of PHPUnit?

Comment: NOTE: the URL now uses https (`curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.php`). I would edit the answer, but that'd require at least 6 character changes.

Answer (score 5):

You must have the folder that contains the PHPUnit source files on your [PHP include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path). Also, `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` was added in 3.6, and it's possible you have an older 3.5.x source folder instead. Check the folders listed using

```
php -r 'foreach (explode(":", get_include_path()) as $path) echo $path . PHP_EOL;'
```

(or on Windows)

```
php -r"foreach (explode(':', get_include_path()) as $path) echo $path . PHP_EOL;"
```

and make sure one of them contains a `PHPUnit` folder with `Autoload.php`.

**Update:** Regarding your update, you probably want to remove `/usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit` from the include path because you're including `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` which should be located in `/usr/local/share/pear` which is already in the include path.

To make sure PHPUnit is working first run `phpunit --version` so you can see the installed version. PHPUnit instantiates all of the test cases it plans to run before outputting anything. If any of your test cases cause a fatal error while loading, sometimes no output is shown at all. This is very frustrating. Start by creating the simplest test case possible that doesn't use any of your code.

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function testThatItWorks() {
        self::assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Running this test should produce a single passing test. Try it and paste what you see in your question.

Comment: thanks. based on your input I was able to make another step to get phpunit working. do you have a suggestion regarding "Update(1)"?

Comment: sorry did not notice the update... I realized that I should have used MAMP to do this and run into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375327/mamp-unable-to-upgrade-pear. I guess my issues are related to that...

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem when I was running `phpunit.phar` from my local directory, but also has PHPUnit installed as a composer dependency. Removing the PHPUnit composer dependency fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the previous answers: double-check with php.ini file is being loaded and make sure you edit THAT file with additional paths. I used the following to check the loaded php.ini

```
php -r 'phpinfo();'
```

Which told me that the loaded php.ini file was **/private/etc/php.ini**

Then I used "which" to tell me where phpunit had been installed:

```
which phpunit
```

Then I added that path to the php.ini file, so it ended up looking like this:

```
;***** Added by go-pear
include_path=".:/Users/admin/pear/share/pear:/php/includes:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/php/"
```

Only after I had done all that did the "phpunit --version" and other commands work as expected.

Comment: You can do php -i instead of invoking phpinfo()

Comment: "To add to this" -- to add to what?

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that most users who face the problem faced here  must be running the command

**$ phpunit**

from the command prompt. when they get the above error. What Most of us fail to understand about the real issue is that the PHP used on the command prompt will mostly be very different from the one running things for  you in your webserver.  Personally i use lampp and even though i had correctly installed phpunit using  pear successfully,i failed to realised this essential part for hours.

**Remedy**
 - for anytime you need to run a PHP script that requires resources in the include_path, make sure that php.ini for the respective PHP binary your using is adequately furnished. case and point in my ubuntu 12.04 installation with xampp my two php binaries include

- the command line one i.e php5-cli found in /etc/php5/cli/ directory
- the xampp one i.e php that is used by apache to serve my pages found in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

Both the php.ini files must have your desirable and correct include_path declaration for you to correctly bootstrap any command line scripts and serverside(apache served scripts).

**Back to our matter at hand after correctly configuring  the php.ini remember to**

- Restart Apache so that the web server pick your changes
- Restart you terminal/commandline session so that the cli prompt picks your changes

**Common Mistakes that get you problems when Changing Files in Linux/*nix Systems**

- remember to run chwon to own the php.ini file  or else you wont even manage to edit them
- remember to run chmod and change the values to allow you to save your changes after which you can return everything (access control on file i.e chwon and chmod to the previous state) to the way they were and  it should be ok after restarting the terminal and apache.

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

The remark of Howard Lo on Mac OSX is very useful **with** the remark of Sebastian Perez. Because the remark is not that nice formatted, it maybe overlooked. After the Mavericks update of OSX I ran for the second time to this issue, U decided to create this full Apple OSX solution for this problem. I have to say I have also installed MAMP-PRO with several different version of php, so I need to be very accurate.

1. Check if you have an php.ini installed into /private/etc. If not issue the command:

   $ sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini
2. Get the latest php archive of pear

   $ curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.php
3. Install the archive with

   $ sudo php -q go-pear.php
4. During installation, it detects if the include_path in your php.ini does not contain the PEAR PHP directory. You can choose to let it fix it for you automatically when given the option.
5. After these steps I had to install phpunit again using the following commands:

   $ sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

   $ sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no

   $ sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

   $ sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit

Many thanks to Howard Lo and Sebastian Perez.