# MAMP: How to upgrade PEAR

Tags: macos, osx-lion, pear, mamp

When trying to upgrade MAMP pear the following error is raised:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 276 of 1133 bytes in Config.php on line 1050
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted.
```

Some suggestions how to fix this?

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Installed MAMP (version 2.0.5)
- cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin
- sudo ./pear upgrade pear
- above mentioned error is thrown

**Update (1):**

Based on answer [8375349/420953](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8375349/420953) I tried 2 possibilities to fix this

- A: **delete** pear.conf

  - rm /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf
- B: **edit** pear.conf

  - change "php_dir";s:44 to "php_dir";s:**43**

both resulted in error:

```
Could not get contents of package "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear". Invalid tgz file.
upgrade failed
```

**Update (2):**

running

- which pear

results in output

- /usr/local/bin/pear

With this, I noticed that I was using the "local" version of PEAR.

I removed it with

- sudo pear uninstall pear

and then tried to upgrade the MAMP version of PEAR with

- /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear upgrade pear

this results in error

```
Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pear.php.net" is not writeable by the current user
```

upgrading with

- sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear upgrade pear

installs it locally (again).

running

- which pear

outputs

- /usr/local/bin/pear

this brings me back to the starting point of **Update (2)**. Seems that I am not able to upgrade PEAR under a MAMP directory.

**Update (3):**

I posted question

- [MAMP PEAR configuration is pointing to local directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482265/mamp-pear-configuration-is-pointing-to-local-directories)

because my assumption is that the root of this issue is related to MAMP PEAR config.

**Update (4):**

I did not install a local PEAR version and this was causing quite some issues. After also installing a local version (and not only the MAMP) version, upgarding the MAMP version worked perfectly.

Comment: `rm /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf` worked for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

People with the your exact problem seem to has solved it in [this MAMP forum thread](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?t=13815).

You can either delete `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf`, or change a line in that file from `"php_dir";s:44` to `"php_dir";s:43`.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work out. please take a look at Update(1) in my question.

Comment: I'd recommend removing and reinstalling MAMP, then trying the fix again.

Comment: fixed the "collateral" issue -> Update(4). your initial answer is correct. thanks.

Comment: On /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pecl install mongo
I got Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 276 of 1133 bytes in Config.php on line 1050
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted and the suggestion to delete pear.conf solved it for me!

Answer (score 4):

Edit the pear.conf: Adding a forward slash "/" to the end of the php_dir path, while keeping the s:44 solved the problem for me and a couple coworkers.

Answer (score 2):

I have XAMPP installed, and I just deleted /xampp/php/pear.ini and that solved the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Just chipping in with a late response for others finding this answer. My PEAR config had several issues and not just the php_dir config setting.

I had to go over all of my settings to verify that the count was correct. When all errors where fixed my PEAR was working fine again.

Seeing this message in the terminal:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 276 of 1133 bytes in Config.php on line 1050
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted.
```

1. Go to your PEAR Config file (probably located here `/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/conf/pear.conf`)
2. Go to the 276th character in that file and verify that the string length matches the s43 that's defined before the string.
3. Run a PEAR command again (e.g. `pear version`)
4. If you have more errors located at e.g. 317th character you count that string and write the length in the s:XX before the string.

Just for clarifying for others finding this issue. The PEAR Config file is a serialized object that is unserialized when running commands.

A serialized object looks like `s:5:"value"` with the s:5 defining the length the string.