# MAMP PEAR configuration is pointing to local directories

Tags: macos, pear, mamp

I am using MAMP 2.0.5 and I have an issue upgrading PEAR

- [MAMP: How to upgrade PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375327/mamp-unable-to-upgrade-pear)

The issue is that PEAR is always installed in the "local" PEAR directory instead of the MAMP PEAR directory.

My MAMP PEAR configuration is the following:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear config-show

Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/local/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/local/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/local/share/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/local/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/local/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/install
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/install
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/local/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/local/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/local/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /Applications/MAMP/conf/php/php5.3.6/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /Users/udos/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf
```

My question(s):

- Is it correct that MAMP is using "local" directories to install PEAR?
- Could someone point out how a "correct" MAMP PEAR configuration should look like?

Some suggestions how to fix?

**Update (1):**

first I switched to MAMP bin dir

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/
```

checked the content of the directory

```
ls -al
total 56080
drwxr-xr-x  10 udos  admin       340 Dec 26 11:40 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 udos  admin       238 Dec 10 14:09 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 udos  admin       924 Dec 26 11:40 pear
-rwxr-xr-x   1 udos  admin       945 Dec 26 11:40 peardev
-rwxr-xr-x   1 udos  admin       861 Dec 26 11:40 pecl
-rwxr-xr-x   1 udos  admin     14821 Dec 26 11:40 phar
-rwxr-xr-x   1 udos  admin     14821 Dec 26 11:40 phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x   1 udos  admin  28652364 Dec 26 11:40 php
-rwxr-xr-x   1 udos  admin      3892 Dec 26 11:40 php-config
-rwxr-xr-x   1 udos  admin      4582 Dec 26 11:40 phpize
```

after applying the changes according willems [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482265/mamp-pear-configuration-is-pointing-to-local-directories/8631729#8631729) my config looks like this

```
./pear config-show

Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/local/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/doc/
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/data/
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/install
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/install
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/test/
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/local/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /Applications/MAMP/conf/php/php5.3.6/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /Users/udos/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf
```

running

```
./pear upgrade --force
```

updates PEAR displaying the following:

```
downloading Archive_Tar-1.3.8.tgz ...
Starting to download Archive_Tar-1.3.8.tgz (17,995 bytes)
......done: 17,995 bytes
downloading Console_Getopt-1.3.1.tgz ...
Starting to download Console_Getopt-1.3.1.tgz (4,471 bytes)
...done: 4,471 bytes
downloading PEAR-1.9.4.tgz ...
Starting to download PEAR-1.9.4.tgz (296,332 bytes)
...done: 296,332 bytes
downloading Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz (30,318 bytes)
...done: 30,318 bytes
downloading XML_Util-1.2.1.tgz ...
Starting to download XML_Util-1.2.1.tgz (17,729 bytes)
...done: 17,729 bytes
upgrade ok: channel://pear.php.net/Archive_Tar-1.3.8
upgrade ok: channel://pear.php.net/Console_Getopt-1.3.1
upgrade ok: channel://pear.php.net/Structures_Graph-1.0.4
upgrade ok: channel://pear.php.net/XML_Util-1.2.1
upgrade ok: channel://pear.php.net/PEAR-1.9.4
PEAR: Optional feature webinstaller available (PEAR's web-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtkinstaller available (PEAR's PHP-GTK-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtk2installer available (PEAR's PHP-GTK2-based installer)
PEAR: To install optional features use "pear install pear/PEAR#featurename"
```

check PEAR version generates the following error

```
AirTime:bin udos$ ./pear version
-bash: ./pear: No such file or directory
```

this looked strange, so I checked the content of bin dir

```
AirTime:bin udos$ ls -al
total 56056
drwxr-xr-x  7 udos  admin       238 Dec 26 11:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 udos  admin       238 Dec 10 14:09 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 udos  admin     14821 Dec 26 11:40 phar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 udos  admin     14821 Dec 26 11:40 phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 udos  admin  28652364 Dec 26 11:40 php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 udos  admin      3892 Dec 26 11:40 php-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 udos  admin      4582 Dec 26 11:40 phpize
```

some files are missing:

- pear
- peardev
- pecl

checking

```
AirTime:bin udos$ which pear
/usr/local/bin/pear
```

reveals that PEAR was installed locally (again)...

Some ideas how to fix?

**Update (2):**

I had to install PEAR locally. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a bit of digging and this seems to resolve the php version issue:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear config-set php_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear config-set doc_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/doc/
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear config-set data_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/data/
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear config-set test_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/test/
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear config-set www_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/www
sudo mkdir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/www
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear config-show
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear config-set cfg_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/cfg
sudo mkdir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/cfg
```

Then just cd to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin` and run `./pear upgrade --force`

This will set all the config files in the .pearrc of your home directory, haven't looked into integrating them into the pear.conf in MAMP..

```
> cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin
> ./pear version
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.3.6
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Darwin willem.local 11.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: thanks for digging into this. unfortunately it is not working yet on my side... I would appreciate it if you could take a look at Update(2) of my question.

Comment: after installing a local PEAR version (not only the MAMP version) the issue was fixed. you pointed to the right direction. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is having this problem, after having the exact problem, my solution was:

`cd /usr`

and create a local install in that directory

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ <MAMP PHP PATH> -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PEAR bundler:

http://github.com/c9s/Onion

you can just run:

```
 $ onion.phar -d bundle
```

to install pear packages into local directory. (without root permission)

Comment: thanks for pointing this alternative out. at the moment I would like to figure out the cause of this issue (to understand)...

Answer (score 1):

For MAMP 2.0.5 with PEAR 1.9.2

I had the same problem and think I came across an easier or at least more obvious solution after some digging and frustration.

Use PEAR's config-set command to change the install directories like so:

pear config-set bin_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin

pear config-set docs_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib

Then continue down the line reassigning paths from local directories to the MAMP installation.

Now:

pear upgrade --force PEAR

That should give you an upgrade of your MAMP PEAR to 1.9.4.

I took a much more convoluted route trying to get PHPUnit working with MAMP that involved transplanting the install manually and later reassigning the config paths, but I think this solution should be sufficient.